# Using Sonarqube with Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sonarqube

I am following [this](https://github.com/octo-technology/sonar-objective-c) article to integrate SonarQube with Xcode and analyse Objective-C code. Though the setup is functional and getting no error/warnings after running the shell script, no violations are shown in the Dashboard. All i get to see is basic metrics like no. of lines of code, no. of files, etc. 
Is there anyone who has tried this and guide me further.
[image]

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the article you have specified above, I have few additions to that. You can follow the steps below,

**Prerequisites**:

- Sonar
- Sonar-runner
- SonarQube Objective-C plugin (Licensed)
- XCTool
- OCLint (violations) and gcovr (code coverage)
- MySql and JDK

**Installation Steps:**

- Download and install MySql dmg. And then start the MySQL server from the System Preferences or via the command line or if restarted it has to be command line.
- To start - `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`
- To restart - `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart`
- To stop - `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop`
- Download and install latest JDK version.
- Go to the terminal and enter the following commands to install the
     prerequisites. (Homebrew is the package
     management system for Mac Operating System. to install homebrew, enter the command -

  ```
  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)")
  ```
- Sonar - `brew install sonar`
- Sonar-runner - `brew install sonar-runner`
- XCTool - `brew install xctool`
- OCLint - `brew install oclint` or

  ```
  brew install https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TonyAnhTran/e1522b93853c5a456b74/raw/157549c7a77261e906fb88bc5606afd8bd727a73/oclint.rb for version 0.8.1(updated))
  ```
- gcovr - `brew install gcovr`

**Configuration:**

**- Set environment path of the Sonar:**

```
export SONAR_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/sonar-runner/2.4/libexec
export SONAR=$SONAR_HOME/bin
export PATH=$SONAR:$PATH
```

finally the command `echo $SONAR_HOME` should return the path - `/usr/local/Cellar/sonar-runner/2.4/libexec`

**- Set up MySql DB:**

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
mysql -u root;
CREATE DATABASE sonar_firstdb;
CREATE USER 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON sonar_firstdb.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
```

**- Set Sonar configuration settings:**

```
vi /usr/local/Cellar/sonar/5.1.2/libexec/conf/sonar.properties
```

You can comment out most options except credentials and mysql and make sure that you enter the correct database name.

**eg:**

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/**sonar_firstdb**?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

.
    vi /usr/local/Cellar/sonar-runner/2.4/libexec/conf/sonar-runner.properties

You can comment out most options except credentials and mysql and make sure that you enter the correct database name.

**eg:**

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar_firstdb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
```

- **Start sonar using the command** -

  ```
  sonar start
  ```

The command will launch sonar so navigate to http://localhost:9000 in your browser of choice. Login (admin/admin) and have a look around.

- **Now you have to install the Objective-C or Swift plugin.**

Move to Settings -> System -> Update Center -> Available Plugins (install the required plugin).

You have to restart the sonar to complete the installation once the pligin is added, And add license key once the plugin is installed.

- through terminal go to the root directory of a project you want sonar to inspect, and create a project specific properties file with the following command:

  ```
  vi sonar-project.properties
  ```

Add the following project specific properties and edit the bolded sections as per your project.

```
// Required configuration 

sonar.projectKey=**com.payoda.wordsudoku**
sonar.projectName=**DragDrop**
sonar.projectVersion=**1.0**
sonar.language=**objc**

// Project description
sonar.projectDescription=**Sample description**

// Path to source directories
sonar.sources=**~/path to your project**
// Path to test directories (comment if no test)
//sonar.tests=testSrcDir


// Xcode project configuration (.xcodeproj or .xcworkspace)
// -> If you have a project: configure only sonar.objectivec.project
// -> If you have a workspace: configure sonar.objectivec.workspace and sonar.objectivec.project
// and use the later to specify which project(s) to include in the analysis (comma separated list)
sonar.objectivec.project=**DragDrop.xcodeproj**
// sonar.objectivec.workspace=myApplication.xcworkspace

// Scheme to build your application
sonar.objectivec.appScheme=**DragDrop**
// Scheme to build and run your tests (comment following line of you don't have any tests)
//sonar.objectivec.testScheme=myApplicationTests

/////////////////////////
// Optional configuration


// Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=**UTF-8**

// JUnit report generated by run-sonar.sh is stored in sonar-reports/TEST-report.xml
// Change it only if you generate the file on your own
// Change it only if you generate the file on your own
// The XML files have to be prefixed by TEST- otherwise they are not processed
// sonar.junit.reportsPath=sonar-reports/

// Cobertura report generated by run-sonar.sh is stored in sonar-reports/coverage.xml

// Change it only if you generate the file on your own
// sonar.objectivec.coverage.reportPattern=sonar-reports/coverage*.xml

// OCLint report generated by run-sonar.sh is stored in sonar-reports/oclint.xml
// Change it only if you generate the file on your own
// sonar.objectivec.oclint.report=sonar-reports/oclint.xml

// Paths to exclude from coverage report (tests, 3rd party libraries etc.)
// sonar.objectivec.excludedPathsFromCoverage=pattern1,pattern2
sonar.objectivec.excludedPathsFromCoverage=.*Tests.*

// Project SCM settings
// sonar.scm.enabled=true
// sonar.scm.url=scm:git:https://...
```

- Save the file and you can reuse the same for other projects.
- In the project root directory run the command - `sonar-runner`

Comment: Yes - I followed this exactly, I still do not see any metrics for duplications of complexity.

Comment: brew install sonar-scanner

Answer (score 0):

You should try it with an older version of SonarQube (< 4.0 usually works).